# Django unit tests fail when ran as a whole and there is GET call to the API

Tags: django, python-2.7, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-1.6

I am facing an issue when I run the tests of my django app with the command

**python manage.py test app_name OR**

**python manage.py test**

All the test cases where I am fetching some data by calling the **GET** API, they seem to fail because there is no data in the response in spite of there being in the test data. The structure which I have followed in my test suite is there is a base class of **django rest framework**'s APITestCase and a set_up method which creates test objects of different models used in the APIs and I inherit this class in my app's test_views class for any particular API 
such as

```
class BaseTest(APITestCase):
  def set_up(self):
       '''
       create the test objects which can be accessed by the main test 
       class.
       '''
       self.person1=  Person.objects.create(.......)

class SomeViewTestCase(BaseTest):
  def setUp(self):
        self.set_up()
  def test_some_api(self):

    url='/xyz/'
    self.client.login(username='testusername3',password='testpassword3')

    response=self.client.get(url,{'person_id':self.person3.id})
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    self.assertEqual(len(response.data),6)
```

So whenever I run the test as 
**./manage.py test abc.tests.test_views.SomeViewTestCase**
it works fine, but when I run as
**./manage.py test abc**

The test above **response.data** has 0 entries and similarly, with the other tests within the same class the data is just not fetched and hence all the asserts fail.

How can I ensure the successful run of the test when they are run as a whole because during deployment they have to go through CI?

The versions of the packages and system configuration are as follows:

Django Version -1.6

Django Rest Framework - 3.1.1

Python -2.7

Operating System - Mac OS(Sierra)

Appreciate the help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your test methods are executed in arbitrary order... And after each test, there's a `tearDown()` method that takes care to "rollback to initial state" so you have isolation between tests execution.

The only part that is shared among them is your `setUp()` method. that is invoked each time a test runs.

This means that if the runner start from the second test method and you only declare your `response.data` in your first test, all tests are gonna fail apart the posted one.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Hi @efkin, thanks for your quick response. As it stands, all my tests have response.data which I assert. What do you propose to fix this issue so that tests run fine?